Getting Com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jsonparser.isexpectednumberonytoken() error in Jboss
I am using Elasticsearch Java client 7.21.1 and Jackson version 2.15.2. We have search template to retrieve the response from Elasticsearch.
Getting the response by using SearchTemplateResponse<ObjectNode> response = restclient.searchtemplate(searchrequest, ObjectNode.class);. We are getting this error:

Com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jsonparser.isexpectednumberonytoken()

In the search template we are using a innerhits and collapse. After trying to update Jackson version to 2.17.0 it is working in Tomcat. But in the Jboss deployment it is getting failed.
I am getting this error only while getting innerhits.
Does Jboss support Jackson 2.17 version? How can I debug further on this?

What makes you think Jboss has failed? Do you have an error or a stack trace? If so, please add it to your question, using the formatting tools provided.

We are getting the response in tomcat deployment, but with the same war we deployed in jboss not getting the response. Getting the below error while hitting the API. Error  - Getting Com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jsonparser.isexpectednumberonytoken() error
